# Android: Styles, Includes don't take impact on preview?

Tags: android, eclipse, android-layout

Is it normal, that [styles](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/themes.html#ApplyingStyles) and includes don't have any effect in preview in Eclipse? The more I get into Layout building the less I can use the preview. Even in the newest SDK Version it's so poorly made.

Comment: Just noticed, if u set the layout_width and ...height attributes of an include, the preview will show it up. But than its not editable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, this has been my experience with the Eclipse layout preview.

Answer (score 0):

The layout preview of Eclipse is not suitable for a real representation of the final layout.

To get a real representation use either an emulator or a real device and the HierarchyViewer if you want to debug your layout.

There exists [DriodDraw](http://www.droiddraw.org/) which is a web-based visual Android layout composition tool written in Java. It is however limited in its functionality and maybe not really what you were looking for.

Comment: I hwas testing DroidDraw. Just like u said, its limited and doesnt really suit my needs. Its more a tool to concept apps.